# How to copy float* to IntPtr?

Tags: c#, marshalling, unsafe

**Short description of my task:**

As parameter of my function I got some buffer (IntPtr).

I need to extract some information from this buffer and copy information to audioFrame.AudioBuffer buffer (IntPtr).

**Problem:**

Needed information placed in channelData[c] (float*), I need to copy this information to destStart (IntPtr).

**Code:**

```
private void SomeFunc(IntPtr buffer)
{

...
AudioFrame audioFrame; // audioFrame.AudioBuffer is IntPtr
...

unsafe
{
    float** channelData = (float**)buffer.ToPointer();
    for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++)
    {
        IntPtr destStart = new IntPtr(audioFrame.AudioBuffer.ToInt64() + (c * audioFrame.ChannelStride));
        Marshal.Copy(channelData[c], 0, destStart, audioFrame.NumSamples); ///< problem in this line, channelData[c] is float*
    }
}

...

}
```

**Edit**
Little more context: I got this buffer from CEF (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp). In fact this function work as callback. When I got new audio data I need to send this data throught NDI (https://www.ndi.tv/)

AudioFrame is wrapper over the NDI structure

```
public struct audio_frame_v2_t
    {
    // The sample-rate of this buffer
    public int  sample_rate;

    // The number of audio channels
    public int  no_channels;

    // The number of audio samples per channel
    public int  no_samples;

    // The timecode of this frame in 100ns intervals
    public Int64    timecode;

    // The audio data
    public IntPtr   p_data;

    // The inter channel stride of the audio channels, in bytes
    public int  channel_stride_in_bytes;

    // Per frame metadata for this frame. This is a NULL terminated UTF8 string that should be
    // in XML format. If you do not want any metadata then you may specify NULL here.
    public IntPtr   p_metadata;

    // This is only valid when receiving a frame and is specified as a 100ns time that was the exact
    // moment that the frame was submitted by the sending side and is generated by the SDK. If this
    // value is NDIlib_recv_timestamp_undefined then this value is not available and is NDIlib_recv_timestamp_undefined.
    public Int64    timestamp;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a little more context?  What are you trying to do?  What is the audio data for?

Comment: OK; so: `channelData[c]` is a `float*, and you want to copy `audioFrame.NumSamples` elements of `float`, to `destStart`, which is `IntPtr` - is that right?

Comment: Which audio library are you using for this? I remember either NAudio or CSCore FLAC getting me into a _very_ similar problem once, and realized they also offered methods to directly work with integral samples rather than float ones, simplyfing what you possibly want to achieve.

Comment: I edited my question with little more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps consider spans here:

```cs
var fromSpan = new Span<float>(channelData[c], audioFrame.NumSamples);
var toSpan = new Span<float>(destStart.ToPointer(), audioFrame.NumSamples);
fromSpan.CopyTo(toSpan);
```

Or `Buffer.MemoryCopy`:

```cs
var size = sizeof(float) * audioFrame.NumSamples;
Buffer.MemoryCopy(channelData[c], destStart.ToPointer(), size, size);
```

(note that in both cases it would be better to include knowledge of the *actual* buffer sizes if you have it, to avoid buffer overflow scenarios; I've just assumed the sizes are valid, for simplicity; there's also `Unsafe.CopyBlock` which works a lot like `Buffer.MemoryCopy`)

Comment: Thank you, Marc. I tried solution with Buffer.MemoryCopy it's worked for me. Could you please say, which of this solution is more effective?

Comment: @ВалентинНикин if you have 3 mechanisms all of which have the same outcome (copying some number of bytes from A to B):L they're all just as effective as each-other; personally I'm a big fan of spans - they give you lots of versatility if you need to inspect the data (without requiring `unsafe` everywhere) - but: if you *don't* need to inspect the data, maybe don't do that?

Comment: I see. I don't need inspect the data. Thank you.